# Insert a break in the webpage using java script

Tags: javascript

its web crawler, once opened the webpage i want to insert a line break , so i tried with java script, below is my code

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("var btn=document.createElement('br');" +"var df =document.evaluate('/html/body/div[1]/p[4]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;"
                     + "df.appendChild(btn);");
```

1. create a element
   2.collect the innerhtml based on my xpath
   3.append br

But while executing i'm getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: df.appendChild is not a function
```

Comment: as I can see, df is a string, appendElement is function of DOM node. Try to execute your script in browser.

Answer (score 0):

df would hold innerHtml (of type string) while you are expeting it to be of type HTMLElement.

I would recommend that you would look for the df element by it's ID (add it if it's not already exists), then use getElementById() to get the HTMLElement to which you could append your

EDIT:

you may try to work directly with singleNodeValue instead of innerHTML:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("var btn=document.createElement('br');" +"var df =document.evaluate('/html/body/div[1]/p[4]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;"
                     + "df.appendChild(btn);");
```

Comment: if i have ID it would be easily but i don't have a ID element in my webpage, so please help me to sort out this

Comment: @Prabu I've modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

`appendChild()` is a function of DOM Nodes. `document.evaluate(xpapth)` returns an `XPathResult` thus the error.

You're trying to call `appendChild()` of `df` which is a `XpathResult`